# How to make gdb break on 'symbol lookup error'

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm using `gdb` to debug my program. It is still work-in-progress so some symbols are not yet defined (and errors are masked out during link). When I run the code I occasionally get '`symbol lookup error`', when an undefined function is called (as expected) and the program immediately finishes.

I would like `gdb` to break at that function call so that I can identify the offending line and program status at that point.

Is there any flag or break point location I could use to make gdb stop prior to the program finishing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any flag or break point location I could use

You can `break _dl_signal_error` or `catch syscall exit_group`.

The latter will stop when you process is about to exit regardless of why that is happening.

**Update:**

When using newer GLIBC versions (at least GLIBC-2.31), use `_dl_signal_exception` instead of `_dl_signal_error`.

Comment: This does break. But the call stack information, which would be useful to inspect, is corrupted.

Comment: @AndresR There shouldn't be anything corrupted about the stack. Installing debug info package for GLIBC might help. Otherwise, you have a different problem: your GDB is too old, or your platform doesn't provide correct unwind descriptors, or something. You should accept this answer and ask a separate question (with *all* the details about your version of GLIBC and GDB and how they are configured).

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, the `break _dl_signal_error` didn't work.   The `catch syscall exit_group` does.

Comment: @JanWielemaker Thanks for the note. Reproduced and updated.